# Why isn't Vue an available tag in the salary calculator?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator

We have the other two major frameworks available, Would it be possible to also have Vue on it as well as it's a very popular framework with an growing amount of jobs for it being available. Furthermore it's generally listed in a good amount of jobs that are available here on SO Jobs, I'd wager more than Xarmin which made it into the calculator tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data used to model salary in the salary calculator comes from our annual [Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018). If you've ever taken that, you probably remember that there is a section on technologies where you are presented with a whole long list of languages, frameworks, platforms, etc, and we ask you if you have used these technologies at a substantive level in the past year.

We work hard to try to get these "right" every year, but certainly have some misses. We also have an open text field asking respondents what they would suggest we include for the next year. You can [look and see what we included on the survey in January 2018](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018#technology-frameworks-libraries-and-tools) that was the basis of this iteration of the calculator. Notice that, unfortunately, [vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) was not included last year. That was probably a miss on our part. Another big one I think we should have included last year was [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker). Each year, we try to include the ones we missed as well as rising important new technologies, and remove sparsely used techs that are not as interesting.

Comment: Thank you for the response Julia I really appreciate it. Could a resonable suggestion be that a thread is created before you lock in the choices for the survey for community input or does something already exist for the yearly surveys?

Comment: Yes, we are planning this year for more detailed user testing of the survey before it hard launches.

Comment: @JuliaSilge I have asked a similar question about Rails. here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373775/why-rubyonrails-is-no-more-an-option-listed-under-frameworks?noredirect=1#comment628475_373775 . Is it the same reason for Rails or its something else?